# How to retrieve all registered natives

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Via the `RegisterNatives` function it is possible to bind a native function to a Java method signature. Now I have the situation where another library calls `RegisterNatives` and I would like to call this function from native C (I cannot call it from Java since the signatures are marked private). 
Is there any way I can retrieve all currently registered functions?

Comment: It is far more probable that the other library just calls `System.load()` or `System.loadLibrary()`, and that the *JVM* calls `RegisterNatives()`. And why do you need to know what native methods another library has registered?

Comment: I KNOW that they are calling RegisterNatives() manually. And I need them because they lie in another library I cannot link against.

Answer (score 0):

At first declare the methods in a header which you want to invoke.

Create a jni interface which you want to invoke from java.

Use the library in your make file as source like -

```
MY_BASE_JNI_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)
JNI_SHARED_LIB_PATH := $(MY_BASE_JNI_PATH)/../lib/shared
LOCAL_LDLIBS := \
            -L$(JNI_SHARED_LIB_PATHH) \
            -ljni_demo
```

Declare header and implement your c code in jni method which you are unable to invoke from java.

If you go through the Android Gingerbread source jni scenario then you can understand well.
Have fun...